Insert into table based on condition in another column
I have the following two tables
table c



id
type




1
B1


2
B2


3
B3



table s



id
s_id
s_type




1
2
C1


2
2
C2


3
3
C2



Now I want to insert new rows in the table s for all rows where B is either B1 or B2. I did this, by using the following statements:
for id in (select id from table where type = 'B1')
        loop
            begin
                next_id = get_next_id('id_seq', next_id, 1000);
                insert into s(id, s_id, s_type)
                values (next_id, id, 'C2');
            end;
        end loop;

for id in (select id from table where type = 'B2')
        loop
            begin
                next_id = get_next_id('id_seq', next_id, 1000);
                insert into s(id, s_id, s_type)
                values (next_id, id, 'C1');
            end;
        end loop;

Now I'm wondering if it would be possible to do that in 1 loop and if so, would it make any sense?

Now I want to update A for all rows where B is either B1 or B2., update with what ? Why are you making insert statements when asking for update ?

Yes, that statement is wrong. Sorry for that. I want to insert. I'll correct it.

INSERT can UPDATE as long as the id column is unique: insert into table(id, A, B)values(next_id, id, 'A3') on conflict(id) do update set B=excluded.B;. If you really want an actual update, you can fit this all in a single statement, without a PL/pgSQL loop - it'll be cleaner and faster that way. How's get_next_id() defined and how's it different from nextval()?

INSERT INTO table(id, A, B)
SELECT 
    get_next_id('id_seq', next_id, 1000),
    id, 
    CASE 
        WHEN B = 'B1' THEN 'A2'
        WHEN B = 'B2' THEN 'A3'
    END
FROM 
    table
WHERE 
    B IN ('B1', 'B2');


You can union a select of each of the input c.types and feed that to a single insert. No PL/pgSQL, no loops, just a native, set-based operation:
demo at db<>fiddle
insert into s
select get_next_id('id_seq', next_id, 1000)
     , id
     , 'C2'
from c
where type='B1'
union all
select get_next_id('id_seq', next_id, 1000)
     , id
     , 'C1'
from c
where type='B2'

Or, as already suggested by @Jan Suchanek, you can run a single select and switch between the two target s.s_types based on the input c.type using a simple case.
insert into s
select get_next_id('id_seq', 'next_id', 1000)
     , id
     , case type when 'B1' then 'C2'
                 when 'B2' then 'C1' end
from c
where type=any(array['B1', 'B2']);

Without an index on the type column, these take about .7s on a 700k sample data set, which drops to about .5s with an index. There's not much difference beyond that - one does two simple scans, the other one with a bit more work on top due to the conditional, both ending up taking about the same amount of time/effort.
